# Access 2003 VBA - Validate XML schema XSD & DOM

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xsd, msxml

I have three XML files in a folder, and also have the one XSD file for these. The user places a number of XML files into the folder, and I need to check they are the correct ones using the schema doc. The XML files themselves do not contain a link within them to any XSD file.

- The AwardsXSDPath variable is the path to the schema file
- The strFileName variable is the path of the XML file being processed
- The StrFileList variable is an array listing each XML file to be
  checked

I have a loop which takes each file in turn and tries to validate them against the XSD ;-

```
'verify the schemas of the three XML files using the XSD file
For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
    strFileName = ImportFolder & strFileList(intFile)
    'Debug.Print strFileName


    objSchemaCache.Add "http://somewhere.com/root", LoadXmlFile(AwardsXSDPath)

    Set xmlDoc = LoadXmlFile(strFileName)
    Set xmlDoc.schemas = objSchemaCache
    Set objErr = xmlDoc.validate()


    If objErr.errorCode = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No errors found"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error parser: " & objErr.errorCode & "; " & objErr.reason
    End If

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
    Set objErr = Nothing

Next intFile
```

I have a function called LoadXmlFile

```
Function LoadXmlFile(Path As String) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set LoadXmlFile = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With LoadXmlFile
        .async = False
        .validateOnParse = False
        .resolveExternals = False
        .Load Path
    End With
End Function
```

The immediate window is showing an error

> Error parser: -1072897500; The node is neither valid nor invalid
>   because no DTD/Schema declaration was found.

I assume this means that the XML file in question has no scheme declaration. I don't have schema declarations in the XML files themselves as they do not come with one. Isn't there a way to verify the XML files to the XSD without having a shcema declaration in the files themselves?

The XSD file ;-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Awards">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Header">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="FinAssType"       type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="FileType"         type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="ExtractDateTime"  type="xs:dateTime" />
              <xs:element name="AwardsFrom"       type="xs:date" />
              <xs:element name="AwardsTo"         type="xs:date"  minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="LACode"           type="xs:int"   minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="OrganisationName" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="SupplierDetails">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="SupplierID"       type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="SupplierName"     type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="SupplierAddress"  type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Records" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="CaseIdentification">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="CaseReference"        type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="DateOfApplication"    type="xs:date" />
                    <xs:element name="ReasonForApplication" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ApplicantDetails">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantTitle"     type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantForename"  type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantSurname"   type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantNINO"      type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="DateOfBirth"        type="xs:date" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantAddress1"  type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantAddress2"  type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantAddress3"  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantAddress4"  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantPostcode"  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantTelNo"     type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ApplicantEmail"     type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="NewAddressDetails" minOccurs="0" >
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="NewAddressMoveDate" type="xs:date"    />
                    <xs:element name="NewAddress1"        type="xs:string"  />
                    <xs:element name="NewAddress2"        type="xs:string"  />
                    <xs:element name="NewAddress3"        type="xs:string"  minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="NewAddress4"        type="xs:string"  minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="NewAddressPostcode" type="xs:string"  minOccurs="0" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ThirdPartyContact">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ThirdPartyRelationship" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ThirdPartyName"         type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ThirdPartyAddressLine1" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ThirdPartyAddressLine2" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="ThirdPartyAddressLine3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ThirdPartyAddressLine4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ThirdPartyPostCode"     type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ThirdPartyTelNo"        type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="ThirdPartyEmail"        type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ClaimDetails">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ItemRequested">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="ClaimID"          type="xs:int" />
                          <xs:element name="AssistanceType"   type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="GoodsType"        type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="AmountRequested"  type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="ItemQuantity"     type="xs:int" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="AwardDetail">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="AwardDate"        type="xs:date" />
                          <xs:element name="AwardValue"       type="xs:decimal" />
                          <xs:element name="QuantityAwarded"  type="xs:int" />
                          <xs:element name="TotalAwardValue"  type="xs:decimal" />
                          <xs:element name="PaymentType"      type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="Recoverable"      type="xs:boolean" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference1Name"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference1Value"  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference2Name"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference2Value"  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference3Name"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference3Value"  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference4Name"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference4Value"  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference5Name"   type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Reference5Value"  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Trailer">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="NoOfRecords"        type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="TotalOfAwardValues" type="xs:decimal" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

One of the XML files is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Awards>
  <Header>
    <FinAssType>XXX</FinAssType>
    <FileType>Awards</FileType>
    <ExtractDateTime>2013-04-03T16:50:15.483</ExtractDateTime>
    <LACode />
    <OrganisationName>Org</OrganisationName>
    <SupplierDetails>
      <SupplierID>3</SupplierID>
      <SupplierName>xxx</SupplierName>
      <SupplierAddress>xxx</SupplierAddress>
    </SupplierDetails>
  </Header>
  <AwardRecords>
    <CaseIdentification>
      <CaseReference>XXX1156</CaseReference>
      <DateOfApplication>2013-03-30</DateOfApplication>
      <ReasonForApplication>Moving Home/Resettlement</ReasonForApplication>
    </CaseIdentification>
    <ApplicantDetails>
      <ApplicantTitle>Mr</ApplicantTitle>
      <ApplicantForename>test</ApplicantForename>
      <ApplicantSurname>test</ApplicantSurname>
      <ApplicantNINO>XX999999X</ApplicantNINO>
      <DateOfBirth>1984-03-03</DateOfBirth>
      <ApplicantAddress1>12</ApplicantAddress1>
      <ApplicantAddress2>1</ApplicantAddress2>
      <ApplicantAddress3>3</ApplicantAddress3>
      <ApplicantAddress4>3</ApplicantAddress4>
      <ApplicantPostcode>m16 7ha</ApplicantPostcode>
      <ApplicantTelNo>01611234567</ApplicantTelNo>
      <ApplicantEmail>test@test.com</ApplicantEmail>
      <DateMovedIn>1991-11-28</DateMovedIn>
    </ApplicantDetails>
    <ClaimDetails>
      <Claim>
        <ItemRequested>
          <ClaimID>20</ClaimID>
          <AssistanceType>Beds and mattresses</AssistanceType>
          <GoodsType>Double bed (standard mattress)</GoodsType>
          <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
        </ItemRequested>
        <AwardDetail>
          <AwardDate>2013-03-30T11:33:27.307</AwardDate>
          <AwardValue>134.03</AwardValue>
          <QuantityAwarded>1</QuantityAwarded>
          <TotalAwardValue>134.03</TotalAwardValue>
          <PaymentType>Delivery to customer</PaymentType>
          <Recoverable>0</Recoverable>
          <Reference1Name>Delivery/accessibility info</Reference1Name>
          <Reference1Value />
          <Reference2Name>Notes</Reference2Name>
          <Reference2Value />
          <Reference3Value />
          <Reference4Value />
          <Reference5Value />
        </AwardDetail>
      </Claim>
    </ClaimDetails>
  </AwardRecords>
  <AwardRecords>
    <CaseIdentification>
      <CaseReference>XXX1483</CaseReference>
      <DateOfApplication>2013-04-03</DateOfApplication>
      <ReasonForApplication>xxx</ReasonForApplication>
    </CaseIdentification>
    <ApplicantDetails>
      <ApplicantTitle>Ms</ApplicantTitle>
      <ApplicantForename>xxx</ApplicantForename>
      <ApplicantSurname>xxx</ApplicantSurname>
      <ApplicantNINO>xxx</ApplicantNINO>
      <DateOfBirth>1959-04-25</DateOfBirth>
      <ApplicantAddress1>xxx</ApplicantAddress1>
      <ApplicantAddress2>xxx</ApplicantAddress2>
      <ApplicantAddress3>xxx</ApplicantAddress3>
      <ApplicantAddress4 />
      <ApplicantPostcode>xxx</ApplicantPostcode>
      <ApplicantTelNo>xxx</ApplicantTelNo>
      <ApplicantEmail />
      <DateMovedIn>2013-04-02</DateMovedIn>
    </ApplicantDetails>
    <ClaimDetails>
      <Claim>
        <ItemRequested>
          <ClaimID>88</ClaimID>
          <AssistanceType>xxx</AssistanceType>
          <GoodsType>xxx</GoodsType>
          <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
        </ItemRequested>
        <AwardDetail>
          <AwardDate>2013-04-03T15:54:55.100</AwardDate>
          <AwardValue>134.03</AwardValue>
          <QuantityAwarded>1</QuantityAwarded>
          <TotalAwardValue>134.03</TotalAwardValue>
          <PaymentType>Delivery to customer</PaymentType>
          <Recoverable>0</Recoverable>
          <Reference1Name>xxx</Reference1Name>
          <Reference1Value />
          <Reference2Name>Notes</Reference2Name>
          <Reference2Value>xxx</Reference2Value>
          <Reference3Value />
          <Reference4Value />
          <Reference5Value />
        </AwardDetail>
      </Claim>
    </ClaimDetails>
  </AwardRecords>
  <Trailer>
    <NoOfRecords>2</NoOfRecords>
    <TotalOfAwardValues>268</TotalOfAwardValues>
  </Trailer>
</Awards>
```

Also, after I have verified using the schema, I am going to need a further loop to iterate through the files and store the contents of the 'Awards/Header/SupplierDetails/SupplierName' node - how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

instead of :
objSchemaCache.Add "http://somewhere.com/root", LoadXmlFile(AwardsXSDPath)

did you try something like this :
objSchemaCache.Add "http://somewhere.com/root", "C:...\PathToMySchema\MySchema.xsd"